# Why can't I receive a trap from localhost?

Tags: snmp, snmpd, snmptrapd

I'm trying to send an SNMP trap from localhost TO localhost. I can't see it coming with tcpdump. I'm using the snmptrap command.

I've covered following scenarios :

Host A send trap to Host B = I get the trap
Host B send trap to Host A = I get the trap

Host A send trap to localhost = I can't get the trap !
Host B send trap to localhost = I can't get the trap !

Host A send a trap to an other network adapter on the host from another subnet = Still can't get the trap.

Is it a configuration issue ?

Tnx

Comment: The trap probably comes in thru the loopback interface, and you're running tcpdump on the en0/eth0 interface. Try with `-i lo`

Comment: oh my god ... thank you ! I lost one hour :(